# Export ASPxGridView with column with multiline text to excel

Tags: asp.net, devexpress, export-to-excel, aspxgridview

Is it possible to export ASPxGridView with column which contains multiline text to excel using ASPxGridViewExporter?

I have an ASPxGridView with column that contains a multiline text.
When I export a grid's data using ASPxGridViewExporter that multiline text is rendered as one line (without line breaks).

I tried both <br/> and "\n" (newline) as line separators.

btw value of property PropertiesTextEdit-EncodeHtml is false on that column.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 2 ways to achieve what you're looking for:

1. Specify WYSIWYG export type in XlsxExportOptionsEx:

   ```
   XlsxExportOptionsEx options = new XlsxExportOptionsEx()
   {
       ExportType = DevExpress.Export.ExportType.WYSIWYG
   };
   ASPxGridView1.ExportToXlsx("Test.xlsx", options);
   ```
2. Tell the exporter you want to have data aware export and handle CustomizeCell event to set cell wrapping to true:

   ```
   XlsxExportOptionsEx options = new XlsxExportOptionsEx()
   {
       ExportType = DevExpress.Export.ExportType.DataAware
   };

   options.CustomizeCell += options_CustomizeCell;

   void options_CustomizeCell(DevExpress.Export.CustomizeCellEventArgs e)
   {
      e.Formatting.Alignment = new XlCellAlignment() { WrapText = true };
      e.Handled = true;    
   }
   ```

   Then use the customized options object for export.

See: https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/T381176

There is also the RenderBrick event which sometimes may be helpful. You may handle it like:

```
gveExporter.RenderBrick += gveExporter_RenderBrick;

void gveExporter_RenderBrick(object sender, DevExpress.Web.ASPxGridViewExportRenderingEventArgs e)
{
    ...
    StringFormat sFormat = new StringFormat(StringFormatFlags.NoWrap);
    BrickStringFormat brickSFormat = new BrickStringFormat(sFormat);
    e.BrickStyle.StringFormat = brickSFormat;
    ...
}
```

But I have not found how to actually force cell wrap there, because StringFormatFlags has only NoWrap among suitable items. In my experience I did have cell wrapping long text in the exported Excel doc, so I've used RenderBrick to switch that wrapping off.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Works for me. Thanks.